# foreach display two times the same row

Tags: php

I don't understand why the foreach displays two times the same row ..

```
if(isset($_POST['idSalarie'])){ 
    $displayForm = $bdd->prepare(
                 'SELECT user_prenom, user_nom, poste_nom 
                  FROM USER 
                      INNER JOIN USER_POSTE_SERVICE ON USER.user_id= USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_poste_id  
                      INNER JOIN POSTE ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE. ups_poste_id = POSTE.poste_id 
                   WHERE user_id = :idSalarie 
                   ORDER BY user_nom ASC');
    $displayForm->bindParam(':idSalarie', $_POST['idSalarie']);
    $displayForm->execute();
    $resDisplayForm=$displayForm->fetch();
    foreach ($resDisplayForm as $key => $value) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'"/>';
    }
}
```

**UPDATE :** 
[this is what the console displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKnEM.png)

Comment: If you run the SQL directly on your database, does it produce duplicate rows?

Comment: no, it returns only 1 row

Comment: Are you sure? You have 2 JOINs and any grouping its very probable it returns more than 1 row.

Comment: So if you know there are only going to be 1 row returned, why are you doing anything in a loop?

Comment: because i got more than 1 input text, there is ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fetch()` by default uses `FETCH_BOTH`.

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set.

Try with -

```
$resDisplayForm=$displayForm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $resDisplayForm=$displayForm->fetch();
```

in this its take normally FETCH_BOTH .. for this happen

**FETCH_BOTH** (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

you also learn from there:-
    http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

**try FETCH_ASSOC**

**FETCH_ASSOC**: returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set

try:--

```
$resDisplayForm=$displayForm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```